# Having ajax trouble when it comes to displaying a selected option

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am terribly failing with an ajax/jquery piece of code I am trying to learn in order to solve a predicament I have.

Below is my ajax:

```
        $('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){
            var search_val = $(this).val();
            $.post("addstudentsession.php", 
            {studenttextarea : search_val}, 
            function(data){
   if (data.length>0){ 
     $("#studentselect").html(data); 
   } 

    });
```

At the moment I am keeping getting a blank page everytime I load my addstudentsession.php script. This is the only script I am working on so I am not sure if I am suppose to link the ajax to itself. But below is what I am trying to do:

I have a drop down menu below:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='20'>EWYGC - 10-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='22'>WDFRK - 11-01-2013 - 10:05</option>
<option value='23'>XJJVS - 12-01-2013 - 10:00</option>
<option value='21'>YANLO - 11-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='24'>YTMVB - 12-01-2013 - 03:00</option>
</select> </p>
```

Below I have a Multiple Select box where it displays a list of students that is taking the select assessment from the drop down menu above:

```
$studentactive = 1;

$currentstudentqry = "
SELECT
ss.SessionId, st.StudentId, st.StudentAlias, st.StudentForename, st.StudentSurname
FROM
Student_Session ss 
INNER JOIN
Student st ON ss.StudentId = st.StudentId
WHERE
(ss.SessionId = ? and st.Active = ?)
ORDER BY st.StudentAlias
";

$currentstudentstmt=$mysqli->prepare($currentassessmentqry);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$currentstudentstmt->bind_param("ii",$sessionsdrop, $stuentactive);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$currentstudentstmt->execute(); 

$currentstudentstmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbStudentId,$dbStudentAlias,$dbStudentForename.$dbStudentSurname);

$currentstudentstmt->store_result();

$studentnum = $currentstudentstmt->num_rows();   

$studentSELECT = '<select name="studenttextarea" id="studentselect" size="6">'.PHP_EOL;      

if($studentnum == 0){

$studentSELECT .= "<option disabled='disabled' class='red' value=''>No Students currently in this Assessment</option>"; 


}else{   

while ( $currentstudentstmt->fetch() ) {

$studentSELECT .= sprintf("<option disabled='disabled' value='%s'>%s - %s s</option>", $dbStudentId, $dbStudentAlias, $dbStudentForename, $dbStudentSurname) . PHP_EOL; 
}

}

$studentSELECT .= '</select>';
```

But I have a little problem, I need a way to be able to display the list of students in the select box when the user has selected an option from the drop down menu. The problem with the php code is that the page has to be submitted to find its results.

So that is why I am trying to use ajax to solve this but what am I doing badly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ajax call as following,

```
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
try {
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
    }
}
}
$('#sessionsDrop').change( function(){
var search_val = $(this).val();
if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {

    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "addstudentsession.php", true);

    XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

}
XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4
            && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {

        y = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                   $("#studentselect").html(y);


        }

};
};

XMLHttpRequestObject.send("studenttextarea=" + search_val);
```